# ModX - main resources for different contexts

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I started using ModX yesterday. Prepared my multilingual website using this tutorial: http://www.multilingual-modx.com/blog/2011/multilingual-websites-with-modx-and-babel.html.

Everything works perfectly. I have two contexts: web (domain.com - English) and nl (domain.nl - Dutch). I translated main resource for nl context as well as other resources.

I faced only one problem: why domain.com returns error 404? It works perfectly for domain.nl/index but cannot make it working for domain.nl.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
Just noticed, that Wayfinder is generating domain.nl/index URL for translation of main resource. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up site_start variable under Context Settings tab. You need to provide an ID of the **existing** and **published** resource.

Please follow [this](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/building-sites/settings/site_start) link for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you linked mentions only the parameters site_url and cultureKey to be set for every context. You should also set http_host to domain.com/domain.nl and site_start to the id of your desired "home resource" for each context in the context settings.

You can probably fit [this description from the modX manual](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Creating+a+Subdomain+from+a+Folder+using+Virtual+Hosts) to your needs.
 (although it is for running a multilingual page with different subdomains).